# NoMethodError when using :include on association in Rails 3 with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Obviously I'm missing something simple here. Here are my two classes and the code I'm calling. When I use :include with find, it blows up and gives me a NoMethodError on the find line. When I don't use :include it works just fine (but obviously doesn't do the join)

**Called Code**

```
def index
    @users = User.find(:all, :include => [:org])
end
```

**Classes**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :org, :primary_key => :org_id
end

class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
    #define primary key because it is not :id
    #because this table is in an old db 
    #that can't be changed
    set_primary_key :org_id

    has_one :user

    def full_name
        "#{emp_fname} #{emp_lname}"
    end
end
```

The exact error

NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each):

Comment: Do you mean for org to have just one user?  Is there a 1:1 relationship between Org and User?  The convention is for the primary key to be named id.  Why are you trying to use org_id as the primary key for org?

Comment: The users table is new, the org table is in a legacy database which we're using for reads. Believe me, I'd change the pk name if I could.

Answer (score 0):

What version of rails are you on? Your tag says 3 - is it 3.1 or one of the 3.0.x series? Regardless, it seems in 3.0.x this :include hash syntax for `find` [isn't supported](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveResource/Base/find/class).

Try `User.includes(:org).find(:all)`.

Comment: was rails 3.0.10. I tried your suggestion and got the same error. The last line in the stack trace is:  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:159:in `set_association_single_records'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a lot of digging and trial and error, basically it was a combination of having one table in one schema and the other in a different schema. By specifying the fully qualified table name for our active record objects, active record stopped throwing up on itself.

So the final code:

Called Code

```
def index
    @users = User.includes(:org)
end
```

Classes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "DOC_REQUEST.USERS"

    belongs_to :org, :primary_key => :org_id
end

class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "AOS.ORG"

    #define primary key because it is not :id
    #because this table is in an old db 
    #that can't be changed
    set_primary_key :org_id

    has_one :user

    def full_name
        "#{emp_fname} #{emp_lname}"
    end
end
```